# Group then loop through both records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a sporting site that I need to create a team one vs team two results page. I'm having a problem with the index page when trying to display team one vs team two.

The data is structured as such in mysql.

```
matchId | teamId | Score
2001233 | 986754 |   4
2001233 | 100765 |   6
```

I'm grouping by `matchId`, but unsure of how to loop through to get both teams.

**Controller**

```
@match = Match.group(:matchId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@matches = Match.group(:matchId).inject([]) do |results, matches|
  teams = Match.where(matchId: matches.matchId)
  results << [matches.matchId, teams.first.teamId, teams.first.score, teams.last.teamId, teams.last.score]
  results
end
```

This will give you an array of arrays in the instance variable `@matches`, each element will look like...

```
[2001233, 986754, 4, 100765, 6]
```